# Is there default Ack response in Andoird Bluetooth with Arduino

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am writing app in Android studio for connecting Android phone with Arduino board HC-05. Bluetooth classic is used. I saw from this post ([Does the BLE stack resend a packet if response is not received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708763/does-the-ble-stack-resend-a-packet-if-response-is-not-received)) that Andorid has default handshaking process for resending not Ack packets. Is that also true in the [simpliest bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data?hl=zh-tw) `.send()` function? Or I need to write it myself like suggested in this post ([How to ensure all data is sent before closing Android BluetoothSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440914/how-to-ensure-all-data-is-sent-before-closing-android-bluetoothsocket))?